# SDN 3.3.0 or SDN 4.0M1?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Currently starting a new Java project with Neo4j (2.2 probably) external server as primary database, we decided to use SDN. This is going to be a year-long project with multiple intermediate releases.
We wonder about whether we should go for the current release (3.3.0) or the very new 4.0.0.M1 version.

Considering this [GraphAware article](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2015/03/24/announcing-spring-data-neo4j-4-0.html), previous [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28816521/4745726) (by Michal Bachman and Michael Hunger) and keeping in mind the SDN 4.0.0.M1 [migration chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.M1/reference/html/#migration) :

- What would be the best choice today ?

Personal consideration : I would definitely go for the 4.0.0M1 considering the improvements done, but then the question evolutes to :

- When (approximately of course) will/should/may the "ready for production" version of SDN4 be released ?
  The answer 1 month earlier was around May, any update about that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly we decided to start with the current release (3.3.0) of SDN which implies the use of Neo4j 2.1.7 for compat issues.

Considering the release of SDN 4 in the near future, we will decide when the time will come if we migrate from 3.3 to 4 depending on the effort required to do such migration.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When do you plan your first release ? We hope to get SDN4 GA out soonish (within one to two months). If that's ok with you I'd start with that.

It's a clean rewrite based on all the things we learned that were not good in SDN3 and all the development that Neo4j + Server + Cypher made since the old SDN was started.

Comment: First release will be in July. This could be risky to go on 4.0 already... What about starting 3.3 and migrate to 4.0 after 4.0 release ? I know there are some changes in the APIs, but what could be the effort of such migration on a 2 month developpments ?

Comment: @Michael - Still SDN 4.0 GA isn't released, what is the expected release date? Also, I came to know that unlike 3.x, data migration for existing data is not required in 4.0, is it correct?

Comment: Yes no data migration and GA in two weeks

Comment: @MichaelHunger - I'm trying to do a POC on SDN 4.0. I want to deploy it as a plugin inside the server but there are lot of changes in 4.0. Does 4.0 supports to be deployed as a plugin at all? If yes, then please provide some configuration steps.